# How to make an avater appear on top and over the edge of a background element in Chakra UI?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, user-interface, chakra-ui

In this case, a picture is definitely worth more than a thousand words.

What I want to achieve can best be depicted by the image below.

[image]

So have the avatar on top of a colored background, but it should appear like it over the edge.

I am using Card component from the Chakar-UI within React, and the code I have is as follows

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {Card, CardBody, CardHeader, Text, Avatar} from '@chakra-ui/react'

...

// in the react component return the following JSX:

<Card width="400px">
   <CardHeader backgroundColor="auditorCard.headerBg1" p={4} zIndex="1">
     <Avatar src='https://link-to-profile.jpg'/>
   </CardHeader>
  <CardBody>
     <Text>Body</Text>
  </CardBody>
</Card>
```

Please how can I make use of CSS/ChakarUI to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the Avatar an absolute position and place it a distance from the top where you get the desired look. In css it looks something like this:

```
.avatar{
  position:absolute;
  top: 2em; /* Or every other quantity that gaves you the desired design */
}
```

On ChakarUI i think it will be something like this:

```
<Avatar position="absolute" top="2em" src='https://link-to-profile.jpg'/>
```